# Spring Cloud Contract - is it Consumer Driven?

Tags: java, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-contract

I'm just starting with Consumer-Driven Contracts for our microservice setup, and as they are mainly Spring Boot apps natural choice is Spring Cloud Contract.
But then comes the confusion. In all examples in docs contracts are defined on the producer side, and consumer retrieves them from maven repo. How it is consumer-driven if the producer defines them?

My understanding was that conceptually consumer defines them as its expectation from the producer for part of the API it uses. In addition to the previous question, is it possible with Spring Cloud Contract to define a contract on the consumer side and verify it on producers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for this question. Yes, Spring Cloud Contract can be consumer-driven or producer driven.

The contract definitions can lay either with the producer or in an external repository. The concept of consumer-driven is not related to the fact where the contract are stored. It's related to the fact who creates them or actually who drives the change of those contracts. Another thing is whether each consumer can define a set of their own requirements. That means that one consumer can have different requirements than another one.

So in Spring Cloud Contract for the producer-driven approach, the producer just creates the contracts and it doesn't really care if different consumers use their API in a different way. The producer of the API creates e.g. 1 contract definition for all the consumers and it's the consumer's problem to align to that contract.

With consumer-driven contracts with Spring Cloud Contract, it's the consumer that suggests the changes and creates the contract definitions. The consumer sends a PR either to the producer team's repo or to a separate repo where all the contract definitions are stored. It's not the producer, but the consumer who does it. The consumer can, in the meantime, create the stubs locally without asking the producer for the permission, and prototype the API. Once the consumer has finished its work and of course talked with the producer team about the changes before, then a pull request can be sent with the suggested changes. Important thing to remember is that each consumer has their own folder with their requirements. E.g. if there are consumers `example1` and `example2` and there's a producer `producer1` then under `producer1`'s contract folder there will be 2 folders, one `example1` and the second `example2`. Both will contain expectations for the particular consumer.

Then the producer takes the PR over and the verification happens on the producer side. The tests are generated. Once the implementation is written and tests are passing the stubs can be uploaded.

Finally, on the consumer side, the consumers can switch to start fetching the uploaded stubs to always get the fresh version of the stubs.

- You can check a video of how full cycle of CDC is done here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDkC_00hhvA
- Consumer Driven Contract tutorial: https://cloud-samples.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tutorials/stubs_per_consumer.html
- Producer Contract tutorial with contracts on the producer side: https://cloud-samples.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tutorials/contracts_on_the_producer_side.html
- Producer Contract tutorial with contracts in an external repo: https://cloud-samples.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tutorials/contracts_external.html

All the workflows related to doing contract tests with Spring Cloud Contract can be found here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Is there complete code somewhere for these tutorials?

Comment: Of course, we generate the tutorial from the Spring Cloud Contract samples - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples

Comment: " The consumer can, in the meantime, create the stubs locally without asking the producer for the permission, and prototype the API. " - Does this mean re-using the stub from last time? Or maybe modifying the last stub file from the provider, updating it with the changes they expect to see at the provider, then running it?

Comment: You can modify the existing contracts, create new ones and convert them into stubs only for your local usage. Then once satisfied with the result, after having a proper conversation with the producer team, you can file a PR with the changes to the contracts