# How to achieve consumer-driven in spring cloud contract?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

The contracts in spring-cloud-contract are created and managed by provider side in most of tutorials. in this case, it happens "provider-driven" instead of "consumer-driven". is this the nature of spring-cloud-contract or can i implement consumer-driven in spring-cloud-contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend a consumer-driven approach where the consumer service team submits contract PRs to the producer repo. You can find a detailed outline of this approach [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-cdc).

Comment: You can also check this post for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309971/spring-cloud-contract-is-it-consumer-driven/57310306#57310306