# Do consumer contracts need to be written manually in Spring Cloud Contracts?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Contrast this with Pact where we write the tests manually. Whenever we run the tests it generates a contract. That makes sense. That way we manage the tests (update them when functionality changes) which automatically updates the contracts. The tests are more closer to real life use cases because they're all step by step interactions based on use case.

In Spring Cloud Contracts, do the consumers directly write the contracts manually? If yes, then how are these contracts tested against the consumer's API?

Comment: Can you check tihs answer please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309971/spring-cloud-contract-is-it-consumer-driven ?